# CBCentralManager's retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:) not yielding CBPeripherals under iOS13?

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios13, cbcentralmanager

I was wondering if anyone ran into the same problem under iOS 13 that the call to CBCentralManager retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:) returns 'null' although there is a ble device paired with the system?

This seems to be a specific problem in combination with iOS13 since if I'm testing the very same code under iOS 12, I'm getting the paired devices as expected.

I already had a look at apple's [core bluetooth documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals) today where, however, i could not find possible deviations which might have arised with iOS 13.

Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the answer in [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120466#378168) helps.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, Jack Hua. After diging a bit deeper, I stumbled upon [this blog post](https://jenx.si/2019/10/02/changed-bluetooth-initialization-on-ios13). Basically the issue was related to the fact, that the BLE stack was not ready when i tried to initialize the device.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You can mark you answer later which would help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the issue was related to the fact, that the BLE stack was not ready when i tried to initialize the device (see [here](https://www.jenx.si/2019/10/02/changed-bluetooth-initialization-on-ios13/)).

Answer (score 0):

Move the code for `retrievePeripheral` to the `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` callback to ensure that the BLE stack is on before attempting to retrieve peripherals.